What is the definition of $C^2_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$?
What is the definition of $C^2_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$?
I came across the notation $C^2_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ in Chapter 11, Section 1, Lemma 1, on page 232 of Krylov's Lectures on Elliptic and Parabolic Equations in Sobolev Spaces. However, the book does not explicitly define this notation.
Could someone explain the precise meaning of $C^2_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ in this context?
For reference, I understand that $C^2(\Omega)$ typically denotes the space of functions that are twice continuously differentiable. I am unsure how to interpret the meaning of "local" in this context.
Thank you for your help!

I have seen "converges in $C^n_{loc}$" but not the set.  What was the context for the notation?

Same with Brian. You need context. It is weird to have $C^{2}_{loc}$ because differentiability needs to be defined on open sets, while it is natural to have the local version of $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ because integrability does not have this problem.
